# ProtectedData.Unprotect on an IIS application - fails to work after IISRESET

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7, dpapi

I need to store and retrieve sensitive data from a local database - this data is used by a web application.

In order to protect said data I've opted to make use of the `ProtectedData` class.

The IIS application is running using a specific AD user (Identity property in the Advanced Settings).

Everything works fine until I do an IISRESET - at this point, it seems that the identity is changed for the purposes of the `ProtectedData` class, and I'm left with data I cannot decrypt - I'm getting a `Key not valid for use in specified state` exception.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
    static public string Encrypt(string data)
    {
        var encryptedData = ProtectedData.Protect(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data), entropy, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
    }

    static public string Decrypt(string base64string)
    {
        var encryptedData = Convert.FromBase64String(base64string);
        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ProtectedData.Unprotect(encryptedData, entropy, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser));
    }
```

The `entropy` is obviously static for my application.

What's going on? I was under the impression that `DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser` will use, as the name implies, the current user - which should be, to my knowledge, the application pool identity. Why does it seem like this is changed when I perform an IISRESET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst I don't know why this was happening, I changed the code to use AES encryption instead - this is working fine.

While not an answer to the problem per-say I think it's a valid workaround that deserves mentioning.

**EDIT**:

I think I've found what was causing the issue (I still don't exactly know WHY this is happening, but I did notice something today).

If the web application is using the *ApplicationPool* identity, then all is fine and well and DPAPI should continue working after an IISRESET. **However** if I change the identity to a specific user defined in AD, then things go haywire after the application pool is recycled.

Lucky for me In this particular case I neither need a specific AD user any more and the main encryption is based on AES (DPAPI can't be used to access a shared resource when load balancing comes into the equation) with DPAPI only being used to encrypt the local copy of the AES keys.

Comment: Sadly, no. I did use AES as noted above. On the other hand, it's a far better solution, as in the future load balancing might be used, and in this case multiple web applications wouldn't be able to access shared data protected by DPAPI.

Comment: @Julien I think I found the actual reason - check the edit made to the answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact error when using ASP.NET Core Data Protection API, and for those of you who has this error, please confirm that LoadUserProfile was enabled for the  Application Pool User.