# DPAPI fails to decrypt after restart of IIS

Tags: c#, iis, dpapi

I use the .NET data protection API (DPAPI) to encrypt strings which I save in CRM 2013. The `System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope` is set to `LocalMachine`.
Everything works fine as long as I don't restart IIS. Afterwards it is not possible anymore to decrypt strings which were encrypted before the restart.
The application pool for CRM uses the NetworkService identity to run. It's not really clear to me what's going on here, any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998290/protecteddata-unprotect-on-an-iis-application-fails-to-work-after-iisreset
Problem not solved.